# iframe src full width and height

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, iframe

how can i make iframe src to full width and height ?

for example i have iframe like this

```
<iframe scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" style="border:none;width:100%;height:100&;" allowfullscreen="" src="http://www.example.com/page.php?width=100%&height=100%"></iframe>
```

this is just gonna have full size width and height of `iframe` only.

as you see this part `page.php?width=100%&height=100%`

if i keep it like that, it won't work. even if i make it like this 
`page.php?width=auto&height=auto`

what i need here to make this 
`page.php?width=100%&height=100%` to go full iframe width and height because the content of page.php will be resized if i change the size like this `page.php?width=200&height=200`

anyone help me with this please. appreciate it

Comment: @charlietfl well you gave me an idea of styling the content and yes i have controll of that content so i am almost there and it worked :D thanks a bunch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well passing the url query is a start but you need to use that information to give the page styling:

`src="page.php?fullscreen=true"`

This is just a rough example of what you might try, you may want to change the styles depending on whats necessary for you.

```
<?php if (!empty($_GET['fullscreen'])) {?>
<style>
html, body {
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}
</style>
<?php } ?>
```

You could do something similar passing in width and height independently and then using those values in the css:

`src="page.php?width=500&height=400"`

```
<?php if (!empty($_GET['width']) && !empty($_GET['height'])) {?>
<style>
html, body {
  height:<?php echo $_GET['height']; ?>px;
  width:<?php echo $_GET['width']; ?>px;
}
</style>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: thanks for your time writting all this but i already fixed it with @charlietfl is sulotion. thanks again

Comment: Well since his answer or comment here is not visible you should at least edit your answer to show the solution, or try this and mark it as solved.... it will be helpful to other people in the future.